# MonoGame Draw2D sample allocating lots of byte[] in opentk.platform.android.RepeatTimerTask

Tags: xamarin.android, dalvik, opentk, monogame

I've just run the Draw2D sample for monogame and used the Dalvik Debug Monitor's Allocation Tracker.  I'm getting a ton of allocations as follows:

48 144 byte[]  11  opentk.platform.android.RepeatTimerTask n_run

That's 144 bytes allocated in a byte array inside opentk.platform.android.RepeatTimerTask.

I can't find any info on RepeatTimerTask or why it's allocating memory.  Cany anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a bug in Mono for Android 4.0.4 and it should be fixed in 4.0.5.